# Subtract 3 work days from Date column

Tags: 2013, list, calculated-column

I want to create calculated column that will be 3 work days before date column.
So I want 3 days before certain date.

Comment: Are you looking to use "today" or just the date column?  It should be =[datecolumn]-3

Comment: that is incorrect. because I didn't ask for 3 days before but 3 work days before date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colleague of mine solved it.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-3),2)=6,DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-4),IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-3),2)=7,DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-5),DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-3)))
```

Where **RStartDate** is date column.